# Shall I edit question to new question or just make new question?

Tags: discussion

During investigating question "why in screen session things display incorrectly":

- [symbols display wrong in `screen` - ascii or utf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/646177/9689)

I've found answer what is the reason (i.e. `export LC_PAPER=a4`),
whoever I would love to figure out if there is a way to make this "reason" (i.e. `export LC_PAPER=a4`) work correctly.

Should I rewrite original question or make new question and link them to each other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, I would write a new question: significantly changing an existing one is likely confusing to users that have interacted with it and it feels wrong as soon as it is voted on or it has answers.

Of course, in this case it makes no big difference — there is currently one vote on the [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/646177/315749) and no votes on the only answer (a community wiki with you as the only contributor). Nevertheless, I feel both the question and the answer can be useful as they currently stand.

I am unable to think of any compelling reason to ever prefer significantly changing an existing question over posting a new one. Questions that turn out to be useless can be closed as off-topic. Edits that significantly change the meaning of posts make their history needlessly harder to read.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with [fra-san](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5777/117549) that changing an existing question has risks. In this particular case, there are no other answers, and the existing answer is a self-answer, so I don't see any harm in editing the existing question to refine it.

Questions are free, however, so it'd also be reasonable to leave the existing Q&A (checking the box to accept it when you can), then linking a new question with the new goal.